# how we can delete rows of spam users reviews in pandas

Tags: pandas, string, row, data-cleaning, delete-row

```
PEOPLE   CONDITION                            REVIEWS         
x        pain                                helpful, good
y        1<span>user found this helpful      effective 
z        birth control                       bad product
a        headache                            brilliant 
b        nausea                              can do better
c        24<span>user found this helpful     worst
```

in this dataset how can i delete the rows of span condition , because number before them making unique and i have data of thousands so i can't write every single condition , so using string and for or if condition how can i delete rows with span which is assigned with unique numbers

Comment: use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)